# How to specify validation group for hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, orm, hibernate-validator

I have bean which has two validation groups.

How can I specify for hibernate to use on of them?

I mean it:

```
session.save(myObject)
```

When I make it hibernate validates myObject and save in dataBase - I want to select validation group for myObject.Class

And one more. Hibernate defines database constraints for validation annotations. I want to select validation group for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the groups to validate upon insert, update and delete in your *persistence.xml* or *hibernate.cfg.xml*. Refer to the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e9806) for more details.